# Netflix won't open on clean install of 13.10

Tags: 13.10, wine, netflix, pipelight

I just installed a clean version of 13.10 (Saucy) and tried to install Netflix using [these](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/install-netflix-desktop-app-0-8-in-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-12-04/) instructions.  The installation seemed to go fine, I opened Netflix after and it asked me to install a bunch of extra things through Wine, so I did.  But after that, clicking on the Netflix launcher icon did nothing.  No windows open, no error message...nothing.  Then I tried running `netflix-desktop` from the terminal.  It pauses for maybe ten seconds, then takes me back to the command prompt.  No error messages or anything else is printed at the terminal.  I tried running `wine-browser` too at the terminal and the same thing.  However, if I run either of the aforementioned commands with `sudo`, it prints

```
wine: /home/jacob/.wine-browser is not owned by you
wine: /home/jacob/.wine-browser is not owned by you
wine: /home/jacob/.wine-browser is not owned by you
```

but otherwise the same behavior.  Any idea what's going on?  The only thought I have is that I installed an Nvidia close-source driver (version 319) and maybe that's doing something, but I have no idea.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so turns out that Pipelight is the best solution.  I went ahead and followed their instructions for installing Wine, and it worked like a charm.  It's great because I can run it in my browser of choice, unlike the original method of running netflix, which makes you use Firefox.  If you're having the same problem, try this.  http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

Answer (score -1):

Simply run

```
sudo rm -Rf ~/.wine-browser
```

NOTE that there is NO SPACE between `~/` and `.wine-browser`.

This will solve the problem and let you watch Netflix on Ubuntu.